# Combination vs permutation, question not clear or I am not having the right mindset

Tags: combinatorics

I am having this problem:

> How many 5-player basketball teams can I form from 10 people?

Is this a combination or permutation problem? I see it as a combination problem. The answer should 252.

Also, what would be the answer to this: How many binary sequences (i.e. composed of $0$s and $1$s) of length 7 can I write using exactly five $0$s?

Updated:

Only one row of 4 seats remained in the bus. How many different ways can six friends be accommodated if by chivalry the two girls in the group cannot remain standing? My answer is $\binom{4}{2}4!$, is that right?

Comment: It is a combination problem. And ${10\choose 5} = 252$ is the correct answer.  ${7\choose 5}$ would be the answer to your second question.

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself, perhaps, is what constitutes a team?  Is it just a set of five people, or is it an assignment of five people to five different positions (e.g., PG, SG, SF, PF, C)?  If the former, then it's a combination problem; if it's the latter, it's a permutation problem.

Comment: @DougM The second is a combination as well?

Comment: @BrianTung it s obviously the first interpretation.

Comment: For the second question, you can think of the place holders of digits as candidates for the 1's team.  Now choose 5 to join the team.

Comment: Well, if it's obviously that to you, then good.  Just from the statement alone, I'm not sure one can say that for sure.  (Though I admit playing, say, Kyrie Irving at the five leaves quite a bit to be desired.)  And more to the point, that question can be used as a template for the kind of question you should be asking in general when encountering problems of this sort, when it may not always be as obvious to you as it is here.

Comment: @BrianTung thanks

Comment: @BrianTung I updated another question

Comment: @DougM I added another question, please?

Comment: These should really be added as separate questions.  But anyway, your last question is underspecified.  We are not told whether we care about the particular arrangement of people sitting in the one row, or if it matters who is standing in front of whom, or anything like that.

Comment: right, let s say order doesn't matter.

Comment: In the case of seat order not mattering, we want to split the group of 4 boys and 2 girls into 2 distinguishable groups of 4 and 2. Since the girls have to be on the seat, now we just have to split the group of 4 boys into 2 groups of 2. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to do this. @JalanjiMoh I think your answer is assuming order does matter, as there are 4! ways to arrange the people in the seat once you choose who gets to sit.

Comment: Ok, if assuming the order matters, I am right?

Comment: @BrianTung Let s assume order matter. If it doesn't, then it s $\binom{4}{2}$

Comment: The second question you asked is a combination problem.  The answer is completely determined by choosing which five positions will be occupied by $0$s since the remaining two positions must be occupied by $1$s.  There are $\binom{7}{5}$ such sequences.  The answer to the first problem depends on whether the teams are labeled and whether it matters what positions each person plays.  The answer you gave is correct if the teams are labeled and we do not care about which position each person plays.  Your answer to the third question is correct if we care about who sits and where they sit.